# Raspberry Pi 4 Compute module 4 CM4 no Wifi with Ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 Server on a Raspberry pi CM4 (not the standard pi, the compute module), but cannot figure out how to enable the wifi.  the CM4 has it physically installed and the board's wifi works under raspios (after running through raspi-config and setting it up), but with the ubuntu image provided by ubuntu, i cannot even see wlan0 (or any wifi adapter) when running

```
ifconfig
```

or

```
ls /sys/class/net
```

i am only shown that eth0 and lo exist.  i have a feeling it must have to do with enabling the correct spi port or wifi parameters in the dto, but cannot find any documentation on it.  Anyone else seeing this with the new compute module?

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

My student research group had this issue after flashing RPi/CM4 with Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS; when running `ls /sys/class/net` and `sudo hwinfo --network --short` only eth0 and lo exists.

**Problem solving**

We ran `dmesg | grep -i sdio` and discovered an error regarding failed to load driver for Wi-Fi chipset ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOn0P.jpg)).

When checking the drivers installed, by running `ls /lib/firmware/brcm/` , there were two drivers missing ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO71O.jpg)):

> brcmfmac43455-sdio.txt

> brcmfmac43455-sdio.raspberrypi,4-compute-module.txt

**Solution**

note: be aware of the difference between **43455** and **43456**.

1. We found the first driver on github: https://github.com/RPi-Distro/firmware-nonfree/blob/master/brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.txt

Just download it in the folder using

```
sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RPi-Distro/firmware-nonfree/master/brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.txt
```

2. For the second driver we did not find anything, however, we compared the the following drivers:

> brcmfmac43456-sdio.raspberrypi,4-compute-module.txt

> brcmfmac43455-sdio.raspberrypi,4-model-b.txt

and discovered they where identical. Just duplicate the *brcmfmac43455-sdio.raspberrypi,4-model-b.txt* and rename it to *brcmfmac43456-sdio.raspberrypi,4-compute-module.txt*.

After reboot Wi-Fi works!

**Distro issue?**
We believe this may be a distro-issue..

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue with a remote CM4 I am supposed to work on.

But may I suggest you try installing "Ubuntu Iot Core" snap image and via the serial configure select the Wifi interface and see if that works?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't offically support CM4.. You need 20.10 for that.. 

I'm waiting for 21.04 in April has it has even better support for RPI/CM4.   For example the 20.10 version doesn't support One-Wire devices.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but core will not work for my end application.  as the above comment said, i am using 20.10 in the meantime for beginning development, as that lets the wifi work, and hoping that when 21 LTS is released it will still be as compatible as 20.10